# Eclilpse changing the context root of WebLogic web application

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, weblogic, war

For some reason my Eclipse sometimes changes the context root of my web application in the weblogic.xml file to the name of the project.  The name of the project is different from the context root.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617595/weblogic-application-context-root-is-war-file-name-instead-of-name-specified-in And the example here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/WebLogic_Web_Tutorial#Create_J2EE_application about setting the `deployment descriptor`

Answer (score 3):

Add following property to your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
<m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>my-context</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your workspace, find the following file:

```
{workspace}\{project name}\.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component
```

Then edit it with the following:

```
<property name="context-root" value="your context root"/>
```