# The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI in Struts 2 app

Tags: java, struts2

I'm writing a test application using struts2. In this app I set a context-root in weblogic.xml file:

```
  <context-root>/myapp/test/exec</context-root>
```

And now I tried to access an action with following link:
`http://localhost:8081/myapp/test/exec/myAction.action`

I get `Error 404--Not Found - The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI`

My struts.xml is

```xml
<package extends="struts-default" namespace="/" name="common">
    <action name="myAction" class="com.test.MyAction">
        <result>pages/js/welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Do you have any resource that you can access in the specified url?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16657569/1654265 ?

Comment: My base app is wrote using struts1 framework, but I tried to add a new action using struts2. So, in this case, I enabled the web application framework within the servlet containers web.xml file, I create a struts.xml file and an MyAction class which extends ActionSupport.

Comment: All other action which was wrote using struts1 are called with http://localhost:8081/myapp/test/exec/SayHello.do and this uri work fine

Comment: is not a maven project

Comment: I tried to access http://localhost:8081/myapp/test/exec/pages/js/welcome.jsp and this work fine.

Comment: @Ariana Where is `struts.xml` in the project structure?

Comment: I put it in WEB-INF/classes and the web.xml file in WEB-INF

Comment: @Ariana Did you get the answer?

Comment: Yes, the problem was caused by the conflict between xwork2 jar and xwork-core-2.2.3 jar. I deleted xwork2 jar and now all working fine.

Comment: Your explanation was very good, but not the uri was the real problem in my case

Answer (score 1):

The `struts.xml` should be in `src` or `resources` folder in your project structure. `WEB-INF/classes` is a bad place because this folder might be recreated by the build tool and the file will be removed from the final war.

Without action configuration you can't access action classes from HTTP. However if you use convention plugin or something that generates this configuration based on code conventions then you might find the URLs in the config-browser web site that you can access even if you don't have `struts.xml`

You can read more about action configuration, convention and config-browser plugins on the [Struts guides](http://struts.apache.org/docs/guides.html) site.