# Is there a way to change the URL of a Java webapp without changing the name of the .war with maven?

Tags: java, maven

Currently, when I generate the war file with maven it creates a `test-view.war`, so when I deploy the app (i use weblogic) I have to access the app on the URL `http://127.0.0.1:7001/test-view/`

Is there a way I can change the URL needed to access my app without changing the name of the generated .war? So that I can generate a `test-view.war` file, but I can access the app on the URL I want which is `http://127.0.0.1:7001/test/`

I ask because so far the only response I've seen is to use the `<finalName> </finalname>` tag in your pom but this approach also changes the name of the .war file, which is what I don't want to have to do.

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617595/weblogic-application-context-root-is-war-file-name-instead-of-name-specified-in

Comment: You could change the test-view folder in the tomcat webapps directory and it should do the trick.